# Graylog error on Web Interface in .js file

Tags: installation, graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I have a problem and I believe it may be due to my installation with HTTPS, I came to this conclusion simply because when installing over HTTP this does not happen, ie the problem is certainly due to the lack of any specific configuration in my docker-compose or something like that.

Below is the my docker-compose.yml file, error print and also the Stack Trace that the screen itself shows.

[image]

```
version: '3'
services:
  # MongoDB: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3
    networks:
      - graylog
  # Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.2
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
    networks:
      - graylog
  # Graylog: https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog/
  graylog:
    image: csilveir/graylog
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/graylog:/home/ubuntu/graylog
      - /home/ubuntu/graylog/plugins/graylog-plugin-slack-notification-1.0.4.jar:/usr/share/graylog/plugin/graylog-plugin-slack-notification-1.0.4.jar
    environment:
      # (must be at least 16 characters)!
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_TIMEZONE=America/Sao_Paulo
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_EMAIL=dev@dragonvc.com.br
      - GRAYLOG_IS_MASTER=true

      # HTTPS
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_ENABLE_TLS=true
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_TLS_CERT_FILE=/home/ubuntu/graylog/graylog.crt
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_TLS_KEY_FILE=/home/ubuntu/graylog/graylog.key
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_PUBLISH_URI=https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/


    networks:
      - graylog
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      #- "80:9000"
      - 80:443
      - 443:9000
      - 514:514
      - 514:514/udp
      - 1514:1514/udp
      - 5044:5044
      - 9000:9000
      - 9350:9350
      - 12200-12300:12200-12300
      - 12200-12300:12200-12300/udp
      - 12900:12900
networks:
  graylog:
    driver: bridge
# Volumes for persisting data, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/
volumes:
  mongo_data:
    driver: local
  es_data:
    driver: local
  graylog_journal:
    driver: local
```

> Cannot set property '**data**' of undefined
>
> ```
> Stack Trace:
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property '__data__' of undefined
>     at Array.ye.select (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:227338)
>     at Array.Z.insert (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:224227)
>     at Array.ye.insert (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:227450)
>     at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:350536)
>     at https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:226023
>     at me (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:222388)
>     at Array.Z.each (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:225997)
>     at Array.l (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:350305)
>     at Array.Z.call (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:83:226096)
>     at r._drawAxis (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendors~LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:46:42162)
>     at render (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendors~LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:46:41677)
>     at https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendors~LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:46:40953
>     at https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendors~LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:46:23606
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at e.Graph.render (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendors~LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:46:23586)
>     at Object.drawResultGraph (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:1:203535)
>     at t._renderHistogram (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:1:218539)
>     at t.componentDidMount (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/LoggedInPage.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:1:217792)
>     at t.componentDidMount (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:73:88989)
>     at Ro (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:82395)
>     at Xo (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:85070)
>     at https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:98277
>     at Object.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:35:3284)
>     at Os (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:98212)
>     at Ys (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:97988)
>     at Ss (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:97333)
>     at Ls (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:96354)
>     at Zo (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:95228)
>     at Object.enqueueSetState (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:18:44755)
>     at t.b.setState (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/vendor.91c91d4a31d54d96392a.js:26:1665)
>     at https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/90afab18-75.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:1:2875
>     at l (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/builtins.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:104:88608)
>     at O._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/builtins.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:104:61890)
>     at O._settlePromise (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/builtins.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:104:62690)
>     at O._settlePromise0 (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/builtins.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:104:63389)
>     at O._settlePromises (https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/builtins.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:104:64716)
>     at https://graylog.dragonvc.com.br/assets/builtins.af2f821c666e2573f8ad.js:104:18338
>
> Component Stack:
>
>     in LegacyHistogram
>     in div
>     in t
>     in div
>     in t
>     in t
>     in t
>     in SearchPage
>     in Unknown
>     in n
>     in div
>     in t
>     in div
>     in t
>     in div
>     in AppWithSearchBar
>     in div
>     in t
>     in t
>     in withRouter(t)
>     in div
>     in App
>     in RouterContext
>     in Router
>     in h
>     in t
>     in n
>     in AppFacade
> ```

This error occurs in a .js file, as shown in print:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and resolved it by cleaning browser cache.